# Are there any powerline network devices that are flush with the wall?

Tags: networking, home-networking, powerline-networking

I'm looking for a HomePlug (or other powerline network) device that is as flush with the wall as possible, as it will be placed behind a wall mounted television.

I haven't had any luck trying to find HomePlug (or other powerline network) products that are thin enough to be suitable - do such products exist on the market, or are there any other ways this could be achieved?

** **Edit** **

I should probably mention that I'm in the UK

Comment: Not entirely sure why this is on hold; I described the situation and the problem I'm trying to solve - how to get HomePlug ethernet behind a wall-mounted TV...there is already one answer which answers in a non-product specific way... nevertheless, I've made a small edit to make the question a bit more open and less product orientated.

Comment: Your question might be better if you remove "HomePlug" and use a more generic term.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_line_communication  Failing that...maybe http://diy.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Cocowalla the reason presented in the "put on hold" box under your question fully describes why it's closed.

Comment: @A.M. I'm pretty sure Superuser is (meant to be) the place for home networking questions

Comment: @gronostaj "Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve"... yep, did that...

Comment: @Cocowalla I am just trying to help you get your question taken off hold.  I actually think it is fine as-is, but I am trying to think of ways to get more people to accept it.   Based on http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/, it really does seem like you have an appropriate question.  The only other thing I can think of is phrasing it as "What is the thinnest powerline network device?"

Comment: @ others: There is nothing deeper to learn about the topic (see the link about "shopping questions"), so there is no room for something like "What things should I look for in a powerline network device that fits behind a wall-mounted TV?"  The thing has to be thin...end of story...and there is a specific answer to the question as asked.   Actually, it is even more future-proof than shopping questions since there is not much chance powerline network technology will regress.

Comment: My guess is that the real reason the question is on hold is that it is both almost a shopping question *and* some people may think it is not computer-y enough (being about a mechanical problem).

Answer (score 1):

There are power outlets that recess into the wall that would allow for a homeplug device to be connected and yet be flush.

This is a rather large one, but I am sure there are single wide's out there.
[image: socket]

Then plug in your gear, then hang the TV in front of it.
[image: plug]

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I'm in the UK. I'm not sure if recessed power outlets are available here (possibly due regulations, or maybe just because of our plug design, where the pins are at 90 degrees to the socket) - some quick Googling didn't turn up anything

Comment: I am sure there is a UK version. Basically this is a deep outlet gang box and you put in whatever socket. They should be available online to you.